# Do .NET Core SDK / Runtime and NuGet Package Versions have to match?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

I currently have a ASP.NET Core Application running on ASP.NET Core 3.1.2.

While looking for package updates, i realized, that a lot of Microsoft packages (e.g. Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, ...) have been updated from 3.1.2 (the latest version available when i built the application) to 3.1.5. Also the latest .NET Core SDK and Runtime has been updated to 3.1.5.

Is this a coincidence or is there any connection between .NET Core SDK / Runtime and NuGet package versions?

Also can i update my NuGet packages to 3.1.5 without updating the .NET Core Runtime on my server?

Thanks,
Jens

Comment: Why don't you check the package requirements? It states very clearly th minimum supported version.

Comment: No... You have to only look at the listed supported Frameworks. If it says NetCore 3.x or NetStandard 2.x ... Thats fine.

Comment: The honest answer is: it depends, and it can depend on quite a number of things, such as whether you use a self-contained application for deployment, rather than relying on the version of .NET Core installed on the machine you're deploying to.

In general, a version of the .NET Core SDK ships with a specific ASP.NET Core version built-in to it, and your NuGet package references should not be _greater_ than that version. Otherwise you can get runtime failures when you deploy as the app will be assuming it's targeting the framework that ships with the SDK, so if it's not there it will break.

Comment: @Gusman - According to the dependencies, the packges work fine with .Net Core 3.1 (no patch version stated). Some comments say, that the patch versions should match to avoid potential problems. So not sure if only looking at the requirements / depencencies is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

Generally they don't have to match, unless some reflection that requires some exact version of some assembly (which happens to ASP.NET Core very often).

Due to the semantic versioning of .NET Core platform and packages, updates in the third version must bring no API changes, so they will always build without failure and regular calls to these packages would work properly.